# Read Each row using head tail combination

Tags: unix

Following is the column which I want to read.

```
col
1 
2 
3
4
5
6
.
.
.
n
```

I want to get 1st row value at first iteration , second row value at second iteration and so on using Head ,Tail combination.

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problems in your post and let us know then.

Comment: What do you mean by iteration? Do you want to do something for each line of the file?

Comment: Why do you want to use `head` and `tail` ?